# Conditional random selection

Tags: python, json, random

So i have a JSON file that is populated with recipes, a sample from the file:

```
{
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Lobster roll",
      "type": "fish",
      "ingredients":[
        {"item": "Lobster","amount": 0.5},
        {"item": "Baguette","amount": 8},
        {"item": "Garlic","amount": 2}
      ]
},
{
      "id": 7,
      "name": "Potato and leaks soup",
      "type": "vegetarian",
      "ingredients":[
        {"item": "Water","amount": 0.5},
        {"item": "Potato","amount": 8},
        {"item": "Onion","amount": 2}
      ]
}
```

What i want to achieve is to select random recipes from the JSON-file, for example 7 recipes. But with the condition that at least 25% of them should be of the type: fish. As every recipe is tagged with what type it is in the JSON-file.

I am using the random.sample() function, so how do i get the condition in play here?

```
import json
import random

with open('recipes.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

random = random.sample(data, 7)

for i in range(0, len(random)):
    print(random[i]["name"])
```

Comment: You could select from fish recipes only for 25% of the samples, and either select from non-fish for the rest (for 'exactly' 25% fish recipes) or select from all recipes for the rest.

Comment: A second, possibly worse or better, option would be adding weights to `random.choices()`

Comment: i think that random might be a problem later ( conflicts maybe ? ) maybe better to call it something else.

Comment: hold a list of their ids and shuffle it, take the first 5 recepies and first 2 fish recepies

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments: you could select from fish recipes only for 25% of the samples, and either select from non-fish for the rest (for 'exactly' 25% fish recipes) or select from all recipes for the rest.

That first suggestion would look something like:

```
import json
import random
import math

with open('recipes.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

total = 7
fish = random.sample(d for d in data if d['type']=='fish', ceil(total/4))
other = random.sample(d for d in data if d['type']!='fish', total - ceil(total/4)) 
recipes = fish + other  # you could of course shuffle them, if the type order needs to be random

for i in range(0, len(recipes)):  # note that `random` was renamed to `recipes`
    print(recipes[i]["name"])
```

`random` is renamed to `recipes` because it's a bad idea to 'shadow' builtin and standard library names. Once you do that, you won't be able to use the `random` module easily anymore, and it's confusing to anyone reading your code, including future you.